Is there a way to change the virtual environment you are working on whilst in your python code file?
I am working on some code, for the felk fork of the dolphin emulator, but when I try to load import libraries, it isn't working. I believe this is due to it not working in a previously configured virtual environment. Is there any way to change this virtual environment in my code itself(since dolphin doesn't have a way to change it with a buttons like most IDEs do)?

Not really. A virtual environment determines two things: which program actually executes your script, and the value of sys.path. You can dynamically change the value of sys.path before executing an import statement to affect where Python will look for the requested module, but you can't change the executable mid-stream.
